# React & MobX - Confirmation dialog when a user navigates away from the existing page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, mobx

I have something that looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Prompt } from 'react-router-dom';

const ConfirmationDialog = (props) => {
  if (props.navigatingAway) {
    window.onbeforeunload = () => true;
  } else {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  }
  return (
    <Prompt
      when={props.navigatingAway}
      message="Are you sure?"
    />
  );
};

ConfirmationDialog.propTypes = {
  navigatingAway: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

export default ConfirmationDialog;
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to extend this so that `navigatingAway` actually does something. I don't understand what criteria to use for it, necessarily, just that it should trigger the confirmation window when:

- a user changes the URL and attempts to navigate away
- a user clicks on a link
- a user refreshes the browser

What would be the best way to check for URL changes for `when`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to come up with a way to 'detect' when one of your scenarios is occurring.

> - a user changes the URL and attempts to navigate away
> - a user refreshes the browser

These are already handled by virtue of assigning a callback to `onbeforeunload`.

> - a user clicks on a link

This is already handled by virtue of `Prompt` being rendered, if you're handling navigation with `react-router`.

`props.navigatingAway`, then, would be better named `props.shouldPreventNavigation` or something along those lines, because it should signal IF you should prevent navigating, not whether you ARE navigating.

For example, if you ALWAYS want a prompt to appear before navigation while `ConfirmationDialog` is mounted, then `props.shouldPreventNavigation` should just always be true, and you're done.  A common use case would be to set it to true if there is unsaved data in a form.

[From the docs for `Prompt`:](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Prompt.md)

> Instead of conditionally rendering a `<Prompt>` behind a guard, you can always render it but pass `when={true}` or `when={false}` to prevent or allow navigation accordingly.

To illustrate this, the following two snippets are functionally equivalent, apart from performance and such:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Prompt
            when={this.props.navigatingAway}
            message="Are you sure?"
        />
    )
}
```

```
render() {
    if (this.props.navigatingAway) {
        return (
            <Prompt
                when={true}
                message="Are you sure?"
            />
        )
    }
    return null;
}
```

If `Prompt` isn't working properly out of the box when `when={true}`, then it could be that your routing isn't being properly managed by `react-router`.

As a side note, make sure you consider what happens with `window.onbeforeunload` if, for example, your `ConfirmationDialog` unmounts while it has a callback assigned.  Use the appropriate lifecycle methods to manage this, or things are gonna get weird when you're testing this.